# iOS App Submission with Payment

Tags: ios, payment, credit-card

I developed an iOS application, which can purchase physical products.
User are required to provide credit card information.

My question is, whether I need to provide dummy credit card to Apple, for the review purpose?

Thanks if anyone could help!!!

Comment: No need for dummy credit card to Apple. apple will manage this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policy

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It  depend on which 3rd party API you  had used

1)For inApp purchase? 
If yes than dont worry apple will use sandbox account for this and can test.

2)And for other 3rd party integration Apple will have other sandbox account..
So you just submit it.. and they will take care of everything..

Comment: @TussLászló I had just given the example.. I dont think there is need of down voting..